# Unexpected forcing when evaluating substituted expression in nested function

Tags: r, promise, metaprogramming, lazy-evaluation, substitution

Inspecting how R's promises work, I recognized an effect that I cannot explain. Consider the following code:

```
twice3 <- function(i) {
  eval.subst <- function() eval(substitute(i))

  print("one")
  substitute(i)
  print("two")
  eval(substitute(i))
  print("three")
  eval(substitute(i))
  print("four")
  eval.subst()
  print("five")
  eval.subst()
}
```

This should test a varietey of things that happen when I try to evaluate the expression in a promise, without forcing the promise itself. Here's what I got:

```
> twice3({print("hi"); 10})
[1] "one"
[1] "two"
[1] "hi"
[1] "three"
[1] "hi"
[1] "four"
[1] "hi"
[1] "five"
[1] 10
```

Observations:

- `substitute` alone does not evaluate or force anything.
- `eval(substitute(i))` also does not force the original promise, which I expected. It probably gets out the expression and evaluates it, without touching the value part of `i`.
- `eval.subst`, however, which was supposed to do the same thing as `eval(substitute(i))`, *does* show some unexpected caching. At first, I supposed that only concerned its return value, however...
- As we see after `"five"`, the calling of `eval.subst` has evaluated `i` at that point.

Why is the last effect happening? The only way I could explain it would be that inside `eval.subst`, `i` refers to a closed over thing, and not "directly" to the outside `i`; but in any case, if I substitute first, why would that change anything?

---

**TL;DR** What explains the difference here:

```
> f1 <- function(i) {
+   eval.subst <- function() eval(substitute(i))
+   print('one')
+   eval.subst()
+   print('two')
+   i
+ }
> f1({print('hi'); 10})
[1] "one"
[1] "hi"
[1] "two"
[1] 10

> f2 <- function(i) {
+   print('one')
+   eval(substitute(i))
+   print('two')
+   i
+ }
> f2({print('hi'); 10})
[1] "one"
[1] "hi"
[1] "two"
[1] "hi"
[1] 10
```